# SQL: Application cross-db maintain only one generic schema

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, postgresql

I actually have an application based on MySQL with a schema based on InnoDB (with constraints...)
My co-workers need to import this schema, so I export my schema in SQL files.

For example:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `admins`;
CREATE TABLE `admins` (
  `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `creation_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `close_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `close_reason` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

Now, I would like to have a cross-db application, so:

- I tried to import my previous sql files in PostgreSQL, but it didn't work, my SQL files are mysql-related (for example use of ` character...)
- I tried to export my schema with mysqldump and a compatibility mode "--compatible=ansi" my goal: have a generic sql file compatible with all major SGBD. But it didn't work: PostgreSQL returns error about synthax

compatible=ansi returns:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "admins";
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE "admins" (
  "id" smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  "username" varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  "password" varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  "email" varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  "creation_date" datetime NOT NULL,
  "close_date" datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  "close_reason" varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

I even tried to export with compatibility=postgresql:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "admins";
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE "admins" (
  "id" smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  "username" varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  "password" varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  "email" varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  "creation_date" datetime NOT NULL,
  "close_date" datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  "close_reason" varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

But also didn't work...

I know there are tools to convert MySQL schema to PostgreSQL schema but this isn't the goal...

My question: Is it possible to have only one SQL file compatible with MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite... and don't maintain a SQL file for each SGBD ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question: Is it possible to have only one SQL file compatible with MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite... and don't maintain a SQL file for each SGBD ?

Not easily with raw SQL, unless you wish to use a pathetic subset of the databases' supported features.

SELECTs and DML in SQL can be moderately portable, but DDL is generally a hopeless nightmare for all but the total basics. You'll want an abstraction tool that generates the SQL for you, handling database specific differences in sequences/generated keys, type naming, constraints, index creation, etc.

As just one example, lets look at auto-incrementing values / sequences, as frequently used for synthetic keys:

- MySQL: `integer AUTO_INCREMENT`
- PostgreSQL: `SERIAL` (shorthand for a sequence)
- MS-SQL: `int IDENTITY(1,1)`
- Oracle (below 12c): No direct support, use a sequence.
- Oracle (12c and above): `NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY`

.. and that's just for the very common task of a generated key. Lots of other fun differences exist. For example, MySQL has `tinyint` and `unsigned int`. PostgreSQL does not. PostgreSQL has `bool` and has `bit(n)` bitfields, range-types, PostGIS types, etc etc etc which most other DBs don't have. Even for things that're shared, quirks abound - specifying "4 byte signed integer" across all DBs isn't even trivial.

One option to help is [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) which I've heard good things about. Some people instead use an ORM to manage their DDL generation instead - though those tend to use, again, only the most primitive of database features.

Comment: Ok Thank's ! So I need a higher-level tool to describe my schema and export it for the different db. I will look Liquibase, some ORM, do you know other tools ?